# ngx-bootstrap Dropdown Dropright Placement

Tags: dropdown, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to recreate the basic dropright example for the Bootstrap 4 component: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#dropright using Angular 6 and ngx-bootstrap (3.0.1 as of writing). I have found solutions to get the dropdown to open down (standard) or up (dropup) but dropright isn't working.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap-dropdownplacement

From the docs, there seems to be a "placement" input - https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#dropdown-directive - but there are no examples of this and I've tried attaching it to any one of the elements dropdown, dropdownToggle or *dropdownMenu. Basically this is an important part of a sidebar menu, where the submenu dropright.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get the dropright functionality working with ngx-bootstrap, please?

Sidenote: I have managed to get this working with ng-bootstrap but wouldn't want to switch packages if I don't really have to.

Answer (score 0):

I got your point but I think this happen because of the bootstrap version.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#dropright
if you check this url you will see they are using bootstrap v.4.1 and you are using ngx-bootstrap, both have different CSS classes that's why you facing this issue.

If you want to fix this issue. Please do few step:

1) https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap (npm install bootstrap)

2) Than include in  **angular-cli.json** file, like -

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   "styles.css"
],
```

3) Remove your BsDropdownModule from app.module.ts file

If I missed anything please let me know

Thanks !!

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

If you look under "External Sources" on the left, you'll see that I am including bootstrap.min.css version 4.1.3. 
What you are suggesting will add a dependency for jQuery, which shouldn't be used with Angular.

Comment: Yes I saw that but you are using BsDropdownModule and also bootstrap v.4 , 
So In that case your bootstrap is not working if you want it from bootstrap that you need to include jquery and bootstrap.min.js as well. Thanks !!

Comment: Actually you are merging 2 things the BsDropdownModule, which you are using not work for left/right dropdown section Please check the tutorial. 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns
have a look .. I think it helps thanks !!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you trying to say. ngx-bootstrap is a jQuery-less implementation of Bootstrap. It uses the CSS of Bootstrap (hence me including it) but the implementation is done through Angular directives (mostly). No jQuery is needed. If you look at my code, you'll clearly see that it's a copy of the tutorial you mention.

Comment: I just want to say that the thing you want in ngx-bootstrap, that thing not implemented with using ngx-bootstrap  ..
Read this doc :-
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns

Comment: If you want to implement dropright Placement, you need to use bootstrap with jquery or look for other package which fullfill your requirement or do custom just making some changes in css

Comment: Gotcha, that's what I suspected. I would like to see an example of the "placement" input though - it's not clear what that should do.

Comment: Yes @roland but you can implement using custom css if you want... Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to make the placement work. You should add `container="body"` and of course `placement="top right"`. Although it doesn't work as expected

To show it on top use `[dropup]="true"`